# HK2 InstantiationService nested inject

Tags: parent, instantiation, inject, descriptor, hk2

I m using hk2 as CDI engine.
I have 2 nested injection as in the code below:

```
public class Root {
@Inject
Son son;
 ...
}

public class Son {
@Inject
GrandSon gs; //should i put it here? 
  ...
}

public class GrandSon {

  ...
}
```

These are the Factory classes:

```
public class SonFactory implements Factory<Son>{
    @Inject
    InstantionService is;

    @Inject
    GrandSon gs; //should i put it here? 

    public Son provide(){
      is.getInstantiationData()
      return sonImpl;
    }

    public dispose(Son instance){
   // destroy
    }

}

public GrandsonFactory implements Factory <GrandSon>{
    @Inject
    InstantionService is

    public GrandSon provide(){
      is.getInstantiationData()
      return sonImple;
    }

    public dispose(GrandSon instance){
   // destroy
    }
}
```

i bound both factory as:
    bindFactory(SonFactory.class).to(Son.class).in(RequestScoped.class)
        bindFactory(GrandSonFactory.class).to(GrandSon.class).in(RequestScoped.class)

Now i want just using the InstantionService.getInstantiationData() to get descriptor data from the calling parent inside the GrandSon class. In particular i need to rise back till to the calling Root class inspecting the injectee parent. I can get data from the factory.provide method of Son class, but i cannot get a valid getInstantiationdata() from grandSon class.
What am i wrong with code?

Comment: In your code above I don't see who is providing FirstSon?  I see the Factory providers for Son and GrandSon but not FirstSon.

Comment: Sorry firstson is son ... i edited just now

Comment: There may be an issue with InstantiationService when getting Factory services.  I'll write a unit test and find out

Comment: Ok thanks... let me know

Comment: I'm still not following your example completely.  In particular, you have an implementation of Son with an injected GrandSon, but you also have a Factory<Son> (I think).  It is the Factory that will be called to produce Son according to what you say about binding, so the Injected field of Son will never get filled in (assuming you are newing it up yourself in the Factory<Son>)

Comment: My phone makes me difficult to well edit my post... so sorry again... i have edited it adding the Factory Interface in its right place and the injection of GrandSon object better specified. Well, say the root class is my Jersey service, i want to use Son instance inside it  but i want to trace all the injection stack till to the GrandSon gs object. The injection resolver calls the SonFactory which instantiates a new Son. But son has Grandson to be injected too so the resolver will call GrandsonFactory. I was wondering if is.getInstantiationData() could trace all the stack from the root class.

Comment: i mean the instantiationdata should print something like: root ---> Son --->Grandson with all related metadata.

Comment: I believe I have written a unit test that does show a failure in the InstantiationService of the GrandSon Factory.  I'm about to check it in and will hopefully have a fix soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in HK2.  I have entered the following JIRA:

[Nested Factory Instantation Service Issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-281)

I'll update this answer once this bug gets fixed.  I have checked in a failing test demonstrating the issue

Comment: The underlying bug has been fixed, but now it needs to go through the release cycle in order for Jersey to pick it up